# How can Job be after Genesis 10 and not Genesis 36?

Tags: genesis, job, chronology

As per the chronological bible reading order it says that after Genesis 10 we should be reading Job 1-42. But it didn't make sense to me cause the Temanite and Eliphaz doesn’t come into being until after Edom which is in Gensis 36.

Also, if my understanding of bible chronology is wrong please lead me to the correct way of understanding the chronology.

I am using this as the reference → https://www.biblestudytools.com/bible-reading-plan/chronological.html

Comment: Yep, you're correct and you're confusion is warranted. This "chronological" reading plan is confusing because, frankly, it's wrong. Not to insult those with conservative or traditional views. When Job was written (c. late 6th to 5th century bce, maybe as late as the end of the 2nd century bce), the Jews never felt compelled to read it in the middle of Genesis in any way. I'm not Jewish, but if you would like to read the Old Testament stories in a more chronological way, I highly recommend looking up the Jewish ordering. I find that it reads more sensibly than other orderings in many ways.

Comment: There is much debate on early Bible Chronology - the reference you quote is one person's opinion;  el_maiz has expressed another.  I could express a few more.

Comment: @el_maiz Do you having any links that would show Jewish ordering of the bible.

Comment: You could try this online Tanakh by the New Jewish Publication Society (NJPS) at http://www.taggedtanakh.org/Chapter/Index/english-Gen-1. When you go under "Books" it will list the books in that order (Law, Prophets, Writings). However, even this isn't completely chronological, no single ordering of the Bible is perfect. The books listed first are not necessarily written earliest. And @Dottard has a good point. Everyone has their own opinions, which is why I strongly encourage you to do your own searches on biblical chronology through scholarly sources.

Comment: Job = Jacob son of Isaac

Comment: @R.Emery Job (a prophet) and Jobab (a king) are quite different people.

Comment: I didnt say anything about Jobab

Comment: @R.Emery where in the bible it says Job and Jacob are the same person?

Comment: There is no evidence that Job was the same as Jacob, son of Isaac. This is highly unlikely considering that Job's children were slaughtered and there is no record of this in Gen 28-33 (the story of Jacob's sojourn in Edom).

Answer (score 1):

They are equating Job with Jobab. While that is a possibility I think its more probable the Job is Jacob

Genesis 10

Joktan was the father of:

Almodad, Sheleph, Hazarmaveth, Jerah, 27 Hadoram, Uzal, Diklah, 28 Obal, Abimael, Sheba, 29 Ophir, Havilah and **Jobab**. All these were sons of Joktan.

Note that the list above is in reverse order. Jobab was the first son of Joktan and was born around the same time as Babel was being built